# Installing Conky and get this " Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer?"

Tags: conky

everytime i got into terminal and run

sudo apt-get install conky

i get screen pop up in my terminal saying..

"TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA
 │
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE
 │
 │ IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement
 │ ("EULA") is a legal agreement between you..."

dont know how to get past this and continue with Conky instalation. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Press TAB, "OK" will become highlighted. Hit Enter.

ok this packge was needed for conky style

you can open terminal and install it manual:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

press ok on agree "END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE"

then back and install conky